# Questions deleted by a moderator before they were a moderator cannot be undeleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators, vote-to-undelete

I recently encountered a question that was deleted by a moderator before they became a moderator. I don't agree that that particular question should have been deleted. However, when I went to vote to undelete, it wouldn't let me because a moderator had deleted the post.

[image]

As the image shows, the diamond was actually the second of three close voters (meaning that the moderator didn't cast a binding delete vote in this instance and the vote was cast before they were a moderator).

Is this intended behavior? If so, is it correct?

Also, I haven't found any examples to test this out on, but is the converse true too (that posts deleted by *former* moderators while they were moderators can be undeleted now)? Does the inability to undelete apply to exactly the case where one or more of the delete voters is a current moderator (regardless of whether they were a moderator at the time that the vote was cast)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is currently by-design. We do not store any sort of "IsModerator" flag with deletions to indicate that it was mod-deleted and should be prevented from regular undeletion. The code just looks at all the currently applicable deletion votes and determines if one of them currently has a diamond. This has the side-effect of applying the prevention to all interactions before they became a moderator and (you guessed it) removing the restriction from all of their actions once they are no longer a moderator. Without such a flag being implemented, it is not possible to determine whether a user was a moderator at the time of deletion.

Personally, I support [getting rid of the restriction altogether](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233466/regular-users-should-be-able-to-vote-to-undelete-moderator-deleted-posts) rather than attempting to build onto this system even more. I don't think it is super useful, and moderators could always lock posts if they truly do not want to see it undeleted in the future.

Comment: Wouldn't a suitable check just be `isCurrentlyMod() && isLastInDeletionList()` to prevent this issue and `isLastInDeletionList() && fewerDeletingUsersWhenUsuallyNeeded() && notPostOwner()` to check if the last user might were a mod during deletion and thus the post has been mod deleted?

Comment: Checking they were last would probably work in *most* cases, but would break in race conditions where two users were voting at the same time. I don't consider making the checks way more complicated to be a viable solution here.

Comment: _Without such a flag being implemented, it is not possible to determine whether a user was a moderator at the time of deletion._ Well, you could have a start/end date linked to the mod status, and check that. It could also fix the issue of removing the restriction once they are no longer a mod. – note that I’m not saying it should be done, just that there are alternative solutions.

Comment: @DidierL Except that solution still only works if the moderator only serves one consecutive time period. We have plenty of moderators which have taken a break and come back at a later time. Technically we do store the dates moderator status is added and removed in user history but it's too resource intensive to try and look up that information for every delete voter on every deleted post that is shown.